# Getting parameters from page url

Tags: php, javascript, url, parameters

So, here's the main code, which checks the URL of the current page for the string *?a=* then sets the variable *ee_roomname* to anything after that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ee_roomname = unescape(location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf("?a=")+1))
    if(ee_roomname.indexOf("?") != -1) ee_roomname = "";
</script>
```

But what, if I want to add more variables, maybe after this value. For ex. here's a possible url:

> http://abc.de/fg.html?a=hijk

Thus, the variable *ee_roomname* will be set to *hijk*
Now if we add some more tags, it will look like this:

> http://abc.de/fg.html?a=hijk&b=lmno&c=pqrs

Now *ee_roomname* will be set to *hijk&b=lmno&c=pqrs*, which is not what I want.
I want the code to only track the *a* variable/parameter's value from the URL.

What needs to be changed, and how, in order to make it work?
Maybe provide a code I can use, too. *(not too big fan of "do this and this" and such)*

Comment: Looks like you want something like [this](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/)

Comment: @le_garry Exactly what I was looking for. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function to retrieve url parameters

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

How to retrieve the url parameters in your javascript

```
var first = getUrlVars()["id"];
var second = getUrlVars()["page"];

alert(first);
alert(second);
```

[View the Source](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/)

**For your bonus:** if you split the string at the '?' and take the first half, that will give you the "pure" absolute url.

Comment: just upvoted this because it helped me build a recent tool. Thanks!

Comment: It's pretty sad that I only notice this answer now, you definitely got it right!

Answer (score 2):

to answer the first question, you could also try:

```
<script> 
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var getv = query.split("&");
  var pair = new Array();
  for (var i=0; i < getv.length; i++) {
    pair[i] = getv[i].split("=");
  }
</script>
```

pair is an array of all get variables and values like:
[["h", "1"], ["g", "2"]] if ?h=1&g=2

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the entire url using this [URL Parsing library in JavaScript](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/the-lazy-mans-url-parsing/).